# converting string to gson object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a string output from server and I am trying to extract some values form the string.

Here is the output from server:

```
jsonString =

{
  "MEANING":"reduce",
  "DISPLAY":"",
  "TYPE_CD":1,
  "SELECTED_IND":1,
  "CNT":1,
  "SOURCES":[
              { "a":1 }
            ]
}
```

Code:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
DataObject obj1 = new Gson().fromJson(reader, DataObject.class);
```

DataObject Class:

```
DataObject
{ 
    private int MEANING;
    private int CNT;
    private String TYPE_CD;
    private String DISPLAY;
    private String MEANING;
    private List<Long> SOURCES;

    public String getSourceTypeMeaning()
     {
       return this.MEANING;
     }

    public String getSourceTypeDisplay() 
     {
       return this.DISPLAY;
     }

    public String getSourceTypeCd() 
     {
       return this.TYPE_CD;
     }

    public int getSourceCount() 
     {
       return this.CNT;
     }

    public List<Long> getSourceList() 
     {
       return this.SOURCES;
     }
}
```

but getting this error

```
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 132
```

I am not able to find the issue with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are pointing out that the problem is in the `SOURCES` field, and that's true, but the solutions they're giving are not correct...

You can't use just a `Map` to parse the `SOURCES` field, because this field **is indeed an array**! You have:

```
"SOURCES": [ ... ]
```

Since you have square brackets `[ ]`, you have an array! And it's true there's a `Map`, but it is contained in the array...

So, what you need to parse that field correctly is:

```
private List<Map<String, int>> SOURCES;
```

---

Note that we use a `Map` to allow the content of `SOURCES` to have multiple and unknown values, so that this code could parse **not only** your JSON, **but also** something like:

```
"SOURCES":[
              { "a":1, "b":2 },
              { "c":3 },
              { "x":99, "y":98, "z":97 }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SOURCES` variable should be `Map<String,Long>`,because in JSON string `SOURCES` is key-value collection `("a":1)` where "a" is string and 1 is number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed my code to use HashMap, still getting a error.          private HashMap<String, Long> SOURCES;                          public HashMap<String, Long> getSourceList()                         {
     return this.SOURCES;
} Still getting an error saying "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1"

Comment: -1, wrong answer: `SOURCES` field is clearly a JSON array since it has square brackets `[ ]`...

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
"SOURCES":[
              { "a":1 }
 ]
```

This will represent a List of map not List of long.

So change your `List<long>` to `List<Map<String, Long>>` or `List<Map<Object, Long>>`.

Comment: @shanku sorry to say but I didn't copy the ans. When I submit my ans after that I see that the same ans is already submitted and when I start writting ans there is no ans present at that time.

Comment: -1, wrong answer: `SOURCES` field does represent a `List` since it has square brackets `[ ]`...